# Read data from excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an excel sheet(ms excel 2010) in my D drive named "test". I have data in it as follows

```
 Id                URL  
 1          http://www.sample.com/term=100898731%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text              
 2          http://www.sample.com/term==101120693%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text             
 3          http://www.sample.com/term==100893225%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text     
...........continues ............
```

How do I code in C# to read these URL one by one from the excel sheet and get the numerical value after "term=" ?

Comment: Take a look at http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/Read-the-contents-of-a-worksheet-with-C.aspx

Comment: Did you try Google before asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection mCon;  
        mCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + pathOfFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";");
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand Command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();            
        string strSelectQuery, mstrDBTable;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();            

        strSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + YourSheetName + "]"; 
      // YourSheetName is the sheet in xls from where you want to load data e.g Sheet1$
        if (mCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mCon.Open();
        }
        DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectQuery, mCon);
        DataAdapter.Fill(DTable );
        mCon.Close();
```

Now your Excel sheet are in datatable, Which you can traverse to manipulate the string value in URL

**Edit**

For getting String

```
for(int i = 0; i<Dtable.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    string str = Dtable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    string YourNumber = str.Substring((str.IndexOf('=') + 1), (str.IndexOf('%') - str.IndexOf('=')-1));
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt as I am entirely new to this, what does "mCon"(in the very first line) stand for??

Comment: I am an exception `ex = {"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'D:\\Pub_med'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."}` .But my excel is not is not opened..then why this exception?

Comment: Try to open another file at different location and let me know if same exception occurs or not

Comment: When I right click on the folder containing the excel file and see the properties, "Read Only" is checked, even if I uncheck it when I open properties again it remains "Read Only" as checked..

Comment: There was some issue with permission settings and I have give wrong "pathOfFile". I corrected those and now its working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string fileName = "Activity.xls";
                            savePath += fileName; 
OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(savePath) + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'");
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                                da.Fill(ds, "Activities");
                                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                                conn.Close();
```