# How to create an excel sheet and insert data from List in to it?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I have an excel sheet with a collection of URLs ,I am reading those URLs one by one from the excel and passing the URL to another service to retrieve some data.[As in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517626/read-data-from-excel-sheet)  
Now, I have a class like this

```
 internal class Record
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Now , I created a list of the class `List<Record> rec= new List<Record>();`
And from service I am getting some 100 records and it is in the list **rec** .
What I want to achieve is to create another excel sheet with column name **Id,Url,Name ,Age**
and transfer the data in **rec** to the excel sheet row by row.(That is reverse of what is done in the above link ) The excel should look like,

```
Id              Url                                                                                  Name    Age
1       http://www.sample.com/term=100898731%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text        Tom     10
2       http://www.sample.com/term==101120693%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text       Jerry   11
3       http://www.sample.com/term==100893225%5Buid%5D&cmd=DetailsSearch&report=xml&format=text       Jose    10
```

How to implement the same ??

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered using the [Open XML SDK](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124&ei=KgJMUaX6PImmO4vmgcAI&usg=AFQjCNFVh7-OHeQJmw_KdtM4Cws37jGYbw&sig2=j4owbRMSGaB0r3hprYgOfg&bvm=bv.44158598,d.ZWU)

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, SPREADSHEET_NAME),
    SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    // create the workbook
    spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook ();     // create the worksheet
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet = new Worksheet();

    // create sheet data
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

    // create row
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.First().AppendChild(new Row());

    // create cell with data
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.First().First().AppendChild(          
          new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("101") });

    // save worksheet
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.Save();

    // create the worksheet to workbook relation
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().AppendChild(new Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),
            SheetId = 1,
            Name = "test"
        });

    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

Loop over your List and append more Cells.